# I received an E-mail on a deleted question telling me that it was being edited. How can that be?

Tags: discussion

I deleted a question 19 hours ago and just received and e-mail informing me that it was being edited. I'm concerned that my unanswered questions aren't really being deleted although they they no longer show on my account.

Comment: See the "What does deletion mean for a post?" section of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that.  High rep users (>10K) can see your deleted posts.

Comment: Even if it is a question that was deleted before anybody could respond to it?

Comment: Yes.  Out of curiosity, what was the nature of the edit?  If something is salvageable, someone might  have thought it was worth undeleting.

Comment: It was a question I asked the in the Christian Stack.  Is there any way I can prevent my name being on the question?

Comment: Yes. It can be potentially be dissociated from your account.  Use the Contact Us link at the bottom of the page.